# Regex pattern can't figure out

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex pattern for php. It will only accept the following two patterns.

```
XXXX-XXXX-2
XXXX-XXX-3
```

Here, X = digit

For example, It will accept,

```
1111-1111-2
1234-567-3
7894-753-2
5287-6325-3
```

But it won't accept,

```
526-5248-2
7895-4125-1
7854-856-4
asas-wewe-y
```

and so on.

What will be the regular expression for this type of pattern ?

Comment: May be `\b[1-9]{4}-[1-9]{3,4}-2|3\b`

Comment: it is not clear the difference between 7854-856-4 (fail) and 7894-753-2 (correct)

Comment: Did you see the last 4 is not in the examples...

Comment: @freedev, It's only accept 2 or 3 in the last character, not any other character. Check the two patterns carefully. Then you will understand.

Comment: @FrayneKonok, Your regex won't work as it also accept '0'. Check my question carefully. I clearly mention X = digit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work

```
^\d{4}-\d{3,4}-[23]$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kQ0qI9/1)**

*Regex Breakdown*

```
^ #Start of string
 \d{4} #Match 4 digits
  - #Match - literally
  \d{3,4} #Match 3 or 4 digits
  - #Match - literally
  [23] #Match 2 or 3
$ #End of string
```

Answer (score 2):

## The Answer

There are various ways this can be achieved. Here is one method:

```
^\d{4}-\d{3,4}-(2|3)$
```

## Explanation

1. `\d` will match any number
2. `{4}` will ensure this is matched 4 times
3. `-` will match the hyphen sign
4. `\d` will match any number
5. `{3,4}` will match the number 3 OR 4 times
6. `-` will match the hyphen sign
7. `(2|3)` will match either 2 OR 3

## Test it Online

You can test this online here:

https://regex101.com/r/oE7xG8/2

Comment: @JayBlanchard Apologies, answer amended

Comment: Put the explanation here just in case the other site goes down or removes their history. That way you preserve the answer for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I was already in the process of doing this... :-)